How to view native UI properties in Appium inspector?
Is there a way to see properties of native UI objects i.e., iOS and Android Views, in Appium?
React Native UI elements are visible but UI views created using platform APIs Java and Objective-C and C++ are not seen in the Appium inspector. Without accessible Ids we cannot write Appium tests for UIs written in the native languages.
For example, we'd like to select an icon on a UI view in Appium inspector and get it's Id and check if it's hidden in the inspector. Native UI view properties aren't showing in Appium.
Thanks in advance for feedback.
